# User svg images in GWT ClientBundle (ImageBundle)

Tags: java, gwt, svg, clientbundle

I normally use the GWT ClientBundle for managing my images within my application like this

```
@Source("icons/info.png")
ImageResource info();
```

No I want to switch to .svg graphics but I didn't find a way to use svg in a ClientBundle like SVGResource or something. I know that svg is supported in GWT and there are possibilities to insert those graphics inside GWT, but I would like to use the advantages of the ClientBundle + the advantages of svg.
Has anybody already solved this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ImageResource` is for raster images that the GWT compiler could optimize in one way or another, and you can query for their size.

For vector images like SVG, you can simply use a `DataResource` with a `@MimeType("image/svg+xml")` annotation.

```
@Source("icons/info.svg")
@MimeType("image/svg+xml")
DataResource info();
```

Note that you cannot use a `@sprite` in a `CssResource` then, but you can get the resource's URL to use in, e.g., a `background-image` using `@url`.
You cannot pass the resource to an `Image` widget either, but then you can just pass its `getSafeUri()`.

---

If you want the SVG content instead of using it as an image URL, then you can use a `TextResource`. You'll have to pass it as `setInnerHTML` to an element or `setHTML` to a widget to get it parsed by the browser.

Comment: The DataResource solution in combination with MimeType works good for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is [LIB-GWT-SVG](https://github.com/laaglu/lib-gwt-svg). It supports the latest GWT version (2.7.0) and seems mature.

They implemented [SVG integration with UIBinder](http://www.vectomatic.org/libs/lib-gwt-svg/uibinder-integration-with-lib-gwt-svg) and added [SVGResource](http://www.vectomatic.org/mvn-sites/lib-gwt-svg-latest/apidocs/org/vectomatic/dom/svg/ui/SVGResource.html) class that you can bundle just like a ImageResource

```
@Source(...)
SVGResource bundledResource;
```

Comment: With this I had problems with some svg graphics which were probably not in a valid format for this library. I forgot to say. But with compatible svgs it worked like a charm.

Comment: I think there is a flag to ignore validation, but Thomas Broyer solution is great, you should go with that